# Animation of drawing a circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, geometry, drawing

I'm trying to understand how Matplotlib.animation works by drawing a simple circle, but I don't understand what I am doing wrong

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10,10),ylim=(-10,10))
line, = ax.plot([], [],)
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,
def animate(i):
    x = 3*np.sin(np.radians(i))
    y = 3*np.cos(np.radians(i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,      frames=360, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

It doesn't draw anything and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

x and y need to be arrays of values to plot the line.

You seem to be creating single floats in your animate function.

If you are trying to show the circle gradually appearing, one way to do it would be to create an array of X and Y values at the start, perhaps explicitly from an array of radian values, something like this:

```
rads = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
x = 3*np.sin(rads)
y = 3*np.cos(rads)
```

Then in animate, you assign just a portion of the x and y arrays to the line data.

```
line.set_data(x[0:i], y[0:i])
```

The number of steps for a full circle will no longer be 360, it will be 2Pi/0.01.

You can change the size of the interval, or change the number of animation frames to adjust this.